# Where are the advanced settings in OpenERP 7?

Tags: odoo

In v6.1 you could make advanced configurations directly on the UI, in the `Settings` area.

In v7, where can I customize User Groups, E-mail templates, Automated Actions, Scheduled Actions, ...?

Comment: Not a programming question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it!

- activate the `Technical Features` check box in the user's `Access Rights` tab.

[image]

Comment: You should accept your own answer so people don't read this thinking it's unsolved.